# Calculate number of domino-coverings for a grid

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am trying to solve this question on [SPOJ GNY07H](http://www.spoj.com/problems/GNY07H):
The problem is:

**We wish to tile a grid 4 units high and N units long with rectangles (dominoes) 2 units by one unit (in either orientation).**

**Write a program that takes as input the width, W, of the grid and outputs the number of different ways to tile a 4-by-W grid.**

**Input:
2
3
7**

**Output:
5
11
781**

I know it is a bitmask dynamic programming question.
But, I am not getting correct output by my approach. Could anyone point out mistake in my approach.

Here is the code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <climits>

using namespace std;

int dp[16][4][60];

int solve(int mask, int d, int t)
{
    if(t > 4)   return 0;
    if(d == 0)  return mask == 0;
    if(t == 4)  return solve(mask, d-1, 0);
    int &ret = dp[mask][t][d];
    if(ret != -1)
        return ret;
    ret = 0;
    ret += solve(mask|(1<<t), d, t+1) + solve(mask, d, t+2);
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    int i, j, k, l, n, w;

    scanf("%d", &n);

    while(n--)
    {
        memset(dp, -1, sizeof(dp));
        scanf("%d", &w);
        int ans = solve(0, w, 0);
        printf("%d\n", ans);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The approach works like this:

I work row by row. On each row, for a column, I try putting tiles first horizontally and vertically. *mask* attribute tells which columns are already filled in row+1. So, when tile is placed horizontally at row, then *mask* = *mask* | (1 << column (*t*)) for row-1, otherwise remains the same. I count the total number of possibilities this way. Stop condition for the recursion is when mask is 0 when row (in the program it is *d*) i.e. the row goes to 0. We decrease row (*d*) when all the columns at this level is filled.

Comment: Could you maybe take a few minutes to explain what this is supposed to do? Links don't last forever.

Answer (score 0):

I have not taken the time to fully understand the problem, but just looking at the code, this looks like a caching mechanism without a computation to go with it. At each iteration of the main loop, you set the cache `dp` to all -1, but nowhere else do you sets its contents to anything else. Then in `solve()`, you have a few special cases that return 0, and then a main case that returns the sum of a few recursive calls; but there's no way for those recursive calls to legitimately return anything other than zero, either.

It seems like two things are missing from `solve()`:

1. A limit case where, for some values of d, t, and mask, a numeric value is computed non-recursively; and
2. At some point, the computed value should be stored in `dp`.

In addition, I think the cache `dp` should probably be cleared *outside* the loop in `main()`, although I'm not 100% sure of that.

Comment: sorry, but the cache value is being updated inside the _solve()_ function. **int &ret = dp[mask][t][d]** does the trick.

Comment: Ugh, you're right, sorry. And in fact, "return mask == 0" will return non-zero values, as well. That's what I get for answering questions before having my coffee in the morning.